# MongoDB: Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Permission denied error

Tags: freebsd, startup, mongodb

Mongodb failed to start when launched as a service:

```
service mongodb start
```

with an error:

> Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Permission denied error

What to do to start it properly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cause is the permission setup of the `/tmp` directory!

Resetting the access mode helped:

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
```